# Possible To Kill Someone Through Healing?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In the Wheel of Time books, when someone is healed, the process consumes a lot of energy from their own body, leaving them ravenous and fatigued. That makes me wonder, is it possible within the series to push someone's body too far just by healing them? For example, if someone is already depleted and they receive a serious injury, could the healing process drain them to death?

Comment: are you asking if people who hurt and healed end up dying, or if someone could take a healthy person and use the healing weave on them TILL they died

Comment: Implied it can happen all the time - but the Plot Armor on the main characters is strong.

Comment: @Himarm More the latter. Not necessarily from 100% healthy to dead, but if the healing process itself can kill someone.

Comment: because im pretty sure i can get a quote that says the healing itself could kill them, because their so wounded. moraine may even say it as early as Tam's healing.

Comment: After Mat was healed by the Aes Sedai in Tar Valon from the bond with the dagger, they took a lot of care of him to ensure he didn't starve while recovering from the healing. I'm surprised you have forgotten this master Cauthon.

Comment: @Theyna from that same event, the Amyrlin said "The amount of power used to heal him is very close to the amount of power that will kill him." which I think is far clearer about this topic.

Comment: @MooingDuck I believe both direct and indirect death as a result of healing is relevant, owing to the last part of the question; though you do add some useful info, perhaps able to be formed into part of an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the world of the Wheel of Time it is possible for someone being healed to die through that healing.
https://library.tarvalon.net/index.php?title=Healing

Healing undertaken without sufficient knowledge can kill both the healer and paitent, and if the injuries are too severe then the effort that healing demands of the paitent could cause death.